# Modulus on Number objects in Java

Tags: java, modulus

Are there any safe ways to apply the modulus-function on objects of type Number in Java?

Trying to make a "Number-generic" way to apply a filter on a collection.

Comment: Can you give examples usage you have tried or consider unsafe?

Comment: You need to accept much more than 14% of your questions otherwise people have no incentive to answer any of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The only generic approach would involve working only with methods defined in the abstract `Number` class, so if by "safe" you mean without losing precision, then no, because all of the methods defined in `Number` warn that they may round or truncate the result (except for `floatValue()` and `doubleValue()`, which only round).